# Identical nodes

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, panel

I have added in a panel the possibility to change the image of a specific Image Texture shading node using `column.template_ID(node, "image", new="image.new", open="image.open")` and it works. But the problem is that I need to be able to modify two Image Texture nodes using a single template_id.

I have looked to see if there is a way to detect when the values of a specific node have been modified but I have not seen a way to do it. What would be the most correct way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thinking I have come to a solution. I had never used PointerProperty and there was a pretty simple possible solution.

I have created a PointerProperty with type Image, I have displayed in the UI the property using `column.template_ID(settings, "texture_image", new="image.new", open="image.open")`. To update the two Image Texture nodes I add an update function to the property that do that duty.

```
texture_image: bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name="Texture image",
        type=bpy.types.Image,
        update=update_texture_image
    )
```

Hope it helps someone sometime :)